# SQL Select Statement in Microsoft Access VBA - Need help inserting in Access table as block, not loop

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, vba, adodb

I am trying to do a Select statement from an SQL server using an ADODB connection, within Microsoft Access VBA. The select statement is very complex with calculations and would work better to keep that to try and turn in to a connection with the DB.

I can append the data row by row, but am wondering how I could append as simple as possible as a block of data to save time/vba effort. (Lots of data!)

In order to simplify the example, I have put a basic SQL statement, but if you could review this and let me know if there is a way to append as a recordset block or what would be a better option... The code below works for pasting as a block into excel, and I would think I only need to change that commented out line's method to append in Access...

```
Option Private Module
Private Const DataServer = "GLSSQLMADPS2"
Private Const sqlconstring = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & DataServer & "; Database=PERF_MGMT_BWRSRV_PROD; Trusted_Connection=yes; Connect Timeout = 600"

Sub M2DSQLPull()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT " & _
          "Employee_Token_NR, " & _
          "Null as 'Sum_Month', " & _
          "1000 AS 'Data_ID', " & _
          "DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, MIN(CALL_TS)), 0) AS 'Metric_1' " & _
          "FROM PMBSED_PhoneEvaluations " & _
          "GROUP BY Employee_Token_NR "

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.CommandTimeout = 120
    cn.Open sqlconstring

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open SqlString(i), cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

        'How I would paste in an excel spreadsheet, how do I block paste in an access database?
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(RowNumber, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    RowNumber = RowNumber + rs.RecordCount

    rs.Close

    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Thank you for any assistance!

-Robert

Comment: What do you mean paste in Access database? Create a table? Append to a table? Look into pass-through queries.

Comment: I would like to append the records to an already created Access table.

Comment: Then run append on a pass through query: `INSERT INTO myFinalTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM passthruQuery`